# by/through/with

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

> I found these facts by Google
>
> I found these facts through Google
>
> I found these facts with Google

which one or two of the above sentences sounds natural or correct?

Answer (score 1):

"By Google" is incorrect.
"Through Google" is valid, as is "with Google".  Through is perhaps the better way of describing how you found the facts.

Alternatively, consider "using Google".

Comment: Thanks. Can I say 'by using Google' in this case?

Comment: You can, it's perfectly valid, although a little verbose.  In an informal setting you can omit "by" and just say using, but both are correct.

Comment: In the context of using Google (presumably Google search), I can't think of a scenario where you would use "by".  "by using" is correct, but the "by" is unnecessary and "using" is sufficient - if I think of a scenario I will reply again!

edit - "By Googling" is an informal way of saying "I found the information using google"

Comment: The most natural sounding is using google or by googling them [the facts].

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer 'through', 'via', 'using' or at a push, 'on' Google.

If I wanted to use 'by' I'd turn Google into a verb... by Googling.

'With' is acceptable, just not as comfortable.

Comment: Cheers. I think of a scenario that I boil water with a kettle, can I substitute with in this case with through?

Comment: @Young - You are asking a lot of follow-on questions in the comments. Next time, I suggest you work on your question a little bit more. Instead of merely asking, "Which is correct?" spend a bit more time integrating other questions you may have when you first pose the question.